# Class static pointers initialized to values set in another class's member array

Tags: c++, embedded, static-members, atmelstudio

I have a class with an array of uint8_t as a member variable. When I write to the member array, static members of other classes are overwritten with the values in the array.
I'm using these objects the following way:

```
SystemInit();
Reporting *r = Reporting::Instance();

r->reportCode(d, LIGHTS, 0xDEADBEEF);

SSD1305Params *ssdp = new SSD1305Params();
ssdp->clear(PIXEL_ON);

SSD1305 *disp = SSD1305::Instance();

r->reportCode(d, LIGHTS, (int)disp);
```

In my example, I have a class defined as follows:

```
class SSD1305Params {
  private:
    static const int visible_buffers    = 512;  // Visible buffers
                                                // (width * height) / pix_in_page   
  public:
    uint8_t buffer[visible_buffers];
    void clear(int);
};
```

Its clear function is implemented as follows:

```
void SSD1305Params::clear(int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < visible_buffers; i++) {
        if (val == PIXEL_ON)
            buffer[i] = 0xFF; // <<<< Value overwrites statics
        else
            buffer[i] = 0;    // <<<< Value overwrites statics
    }
 }
```

I have another class implemented as a singleton. This is implemented as follows:

SSD1305.h:

```
class SSD1305 {
  private:
    static SSD1305* instance;
  protected:
    SSD1305();
  public:
    static SSD1305 *Instance();
};
```

SSD1305.cpp:

```
 SSD1305 *SSD1305::instance = 0;

 SSD1305::SSD1305() {

 }

 SSD1305 *SSD1305::Instance() {
    if (instance == 0) {
        instance = new SSD1305();
    }
    return instance;
 }
```

Whenever I call 'clear' in SSD1305Params, the value that's written to buffer overwrites the static member 'instance' in SSD1305. So, whenever I try to get an instance of SSD1305 after calling 'clear' I get a pointer whose value is either 0x00000000 or 0xFFFFFFFF. As such, calling subsequent functions on my SSD1305 object causes a SEGFAULT. This is true for all objects I've implemented as a singleton (including my reporting mechanism).

Why might this be happening? I would think that buffer would have its own space defined when I instantiate SSD1305Params, but it seems to occupy the same space as my other objects' static members.
Thanks!

**EDIT:** If I comment out the creation of ssdp and retrieve where my SSD1305 instance is located, I find that it's at address 0x20000030, which from looking at the memory map is inside a section called data.impure_data:

```
.data.impure_data
                0x20000004       0x60 c:/program files (x86)/atmel/atmel toolchain/arm gcc/native/4.8.1443/arm-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m\libc_s.a(lib_a-impure.o)
 .data._impure_ptr
```

What the heck is going on? I thought it would be in the heap? grrr

**EDIT 2:**

When I retrieve the addresses of my objects through my reporting mechanism (without calling clear), these are their values:

```
Reporting:                0x20000008
ShiftRegisters:           0x20000018 (singleton used inside Reporting)
SSD1305Params:            0x20000030
SSD1305Params->buffer:    0x20000040
SSD1305:                  0x20000248
```

So we can see that the buffer has allocated over 512 bytes. It's actually 520, which I guess is because of some padding that malloc does

Comment: I don't get how the classes are related, and what is `SSD1305WriteParams`? Where and how is `SSD1305Params` used? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: And are you getting any compiler warnings? If you enable more warnings (add e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` when building), do you get any then?

Comment: How are you creating the `SSD1305Params` object?

Comment: Edited to add missing info. I get no warnings for -Wall, and a few in -Wextra, but they're all related to unused argument variables. I added the minimal, complete, and verifiable example - although because it's an embedded system I used a reporting mechanism I wrote instead of using printf. SSD1305WriteParams was a typo - it should have been SSD1305Params.

Comment: Be aware that it is very common for embedded systems to leave out the initialization of objects with static storage duration - the copy-down code required by ISO C/C++ is often omitted to save start up time. Usually referred to in compiler settings as "minimal startup" or some such. Now suppose `visible_buffers` didn't get initialized properly, you'd get something like the described bug. Can you verify that `visible_buffers` is actually 512 in run-time, by checking it with a debugger?

Comment: Could possibly also be the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)?

Comment: Let me figure out how to use the debugger and I'll get back to you. I've looked into the static initialization order problem and I don't think it's that. I'm not referencing other objects when I initialize my static members

Comment: I don't have a debugger that I can use for this platform apparently. What I did instead was print out the address of each of my objects through my reporting mechanism. I've added this to my question.

Comment: When I call clear(), the addresses of objects declared after SSD1305Params are returned as the value from clear(). If I move their declaration to before my declaration of SSD1305Params, they are unaffected. This may do as a workaround, but I'd rather find out the root of the problem. There's no way I can finish the system with this limitation.

Comment: @TheJew72: What is the memory address of `ssdp->buffer` and what is the memory address of `SSD1305::instance`? (Not the value of `SSD1305::instance`, but the value of `&SSD1305::instance`.)

Comment: @Lundin: `visible_buffers` is an Integral Constant Expression, which is not even used as an lvalue in the code. It does not even have a definition (and does not require one). It is a compile-time constant that is used by the compiler as a compile-time constant (otherwise, it would be impossible to compile the code at all). This cannot be affected by any static initialization issues. Moreover, the memory addresses provided by the OP so far seem to show that `SSD1305Params` has the correct size.

Comment: &ssdp->buffer displays 0x20000030, which is the same address as ssdp. This makes sense, since it is a member of a class it is stored as an offset from the address of the class. However, &SSD1305::Instance returns 0x200009094, which is well into heap/stack space